# batch read ini values

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm started study about batch and i got a problem

i have one ini file

***sample.ini***

```
[Path_Info]
path1=c:\one
path2=c:\two
```

***sample.bat***

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('type "sample.ini"') DO SET %%A
:True ( 
 xcopy %path1%\*.* %BU_Temp%\%name1% /e /h /k /y /i /s /d:%M%-%D%-%Y%
 xcopy %path2%\*.* %BU_Temp%\%name2% /e /h /k /y /i /s /d:%M%-%D%-%Y%
 )
```

At that time i want use 'for' to xcopy and make one line?

so i try to `xcopy %path%%i%~~` , `xcopy %path%%%I` and `xcopy %path*%` .... anyway

but I failed.. please help me/

I'm not good in english.. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use delims to split at the equal sign `=` the n tokens should be 1,2 or 1,* meaning `%%a` will be assigned to the text before the `=` and `%%b` will be assigned to the text after `=`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
For /F "tokens=1,*delims==" %%a in ('type "sample.ini"') DO (
    set pathvar=%%b
    echo !pathvar!
)
```

There is more you need to do still to get it to copy to the correct directories as each path seems to go to another %name% in your case.